# How to read data from Kafka Topic with Stream

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect, ksqldb

I would like to create `MY_STREAM` in Kafka that reads the data messages from `MY_TOPIC` and push it to another `TARGET_TOPIC`. Using KSQL statement:

`CREATE STREAM MY_STREAM WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='TARGET_TOPIC') AS SELECT * FROM MY_TOPIC;`

results to an error `MY_TOPIC doesn't exist` . Apparently Stream cannot be created with read access to `MY_TOPIC`. Stream can only read from another Stream. Is there a way to make MY_STREAM to read data from MY_TOPIC?

P.S. Appended later:

Regardless on how Stream was created, with "as select" or not it is created with Topic pushing and pulling data from Stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps review the [101 Course](https://developer.confluent.io/learn-kafka/ksqldb/intro/) videos.

You can `PRINT` a topic to do a basic consumer, but in order to `SELECT`, you need to `CREATE` a `STREAM` over the topic.

For example, `CREATE STREAM MY_STREAM (fields...) WITH (kafka_topic='MY_TOPIC', value_format="...")`

Also, it is redundant to do `CREATE STREAM ... AS SELECT *` without any filter/grouping/calculations since those would be the exact same stream. This use-case should be limited to type-conversions and re-partitioning of topics, which doesn't sound like you're doing.

Comment: `CREATE STREAM MY_STREAM... AS SELECT * FROM ANOTHER_STREAM` statement allows me to create `MY_STREAM` making it read from ANOTHER_STREAM. It will error if I try to `SELECT FROM ANOTHER_TOPIC`

Comment: @alphanumeric [_Registering a stream on a topic by using the `CREATE STREAM` statement is distinct from using the `CREATE STREAM AS SELECT` statement_](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/ksqldb-reference/create-stream/)

Comment: I created MY_TOPIC. it is not linked to any Streams yet. I go ahead and create MY_STREAM. I want MY_STREAM to read data from MY_TOPIC. How should I create MY_STREAM assuring that it reads data from MY_TOPIC?

Comment: What is unclear from the docs? Did you try `CREATE STREAM MY_STREAM (fields...) WITH (kafka_topic='MY_TOPIC', value_format="...")`. Look at the examples on the page I linked.

Comment: I have created MY_STREAM with `CREATE STREAM MY_STREAM  (id INTEGER KEY, gender STRING, name STRING, age INTEGER) WITH (kafka_topic='MY_TOPIC', partitions=1, value_format='JSON');`

Comment: It should yes,for source connectors.